# How to make speech recognizer rwork on whole screen

Tags: android, speech-recognition, ontouchlistener

I am making an application for visually impaired people and for that I want that whenever user touches anywhere on screen the speech recognizer should start.

I have made speech recognizer and other things..but I am not able to make my speech recognizer to work on TouchListener...

TouchListener is not taking the activity as view. application crashes

Complete code is as below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private ListView wordsList;
protected Button TextToSpeech;
/**
 * Called with the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);
Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
Context context;
context = this.getApplicationContext();
Intent Inte = new Intent(context, FallDetection.class);
context.startService(Inte);
Intent Inte1 = new Intent(context, SmsSpeaker.class);
context.startService(Inte1);
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fall Detection Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();

 wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 LinearLayout myScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myscreen); 
// change LinearLayout to your framelayout if it is not a LinearLayout
//View view =(View) findViewById(R.layout.voice_recog);

//wordsList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
 myScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Touch recognised",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
});
```

as of now I am using List for recignizing touch but that is also crashing application with Source not found exception

Layout xml file is as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/myscreen" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: What is your wordsList for? Do you setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: WordList would store the results of the speech recognizer..the possible matches for spoken word............

nope no setOnItemClickListener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/myscreen"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="4dip"
android:text="Click the button and start speaking" />

<Button android:id="@+id/speakButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:onClick="speakButtonClicked"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click Me!" />
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="0.41" >
</ListView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private ListView wordsList;
    protected Button TextToSpeech;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.voice_recog);
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

        Intent Inte = new Intent(this, FallDetection.class);
         startService(Inte);
        Intent Inte1 = new Intent(this, SmsSpeaker.class);
        startService(Inte1);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Fall Detection Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        LinearLayout myScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myscreen); 

        myScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Touch recognised",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();
         startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer, in my app I did onClick and it works. You should also request full screen put these on the line above setContenView() requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: thanx Hoan....I did as you said...but it is giving error as...........................................The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Comment: I think you import the wrong thing should be import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: nope imported that only...but it is not recognizing the touch still

Comment: did you remove worldlist onTouchListener?

Comment: I edited my answer. setOnClickListener should be public void onClick(view v)

Comment: You still have not change the layout file but anyway let me change and then you just copy and paste.

Comment: I have changed he layout file...just did not upload it.................................uploaded just now

Comment: Just add this line before the toast in onClick to see if you get anything in logcat Log.d("MainActivity", "onClick");

Comment: In your xml add this line to ListView android:clickable="false"

Comment: One last try my layout and your only differ by a scroll view and a listview so let put a scroll view in your and see if it work. But before doing that let put android:clickable="true" just above the line android:orientation="vertical" and see if it work. Let me know

Comment: you mean to say I should replace my list view with scroll view?

Comment: No, Just add the scroll view as the outermost parent. I suspect that the problem is the list view. Anyway did you try what I commented above?

Comment: Sorry @Hoan for late reply...but it did not work....I tried putting scroll view but it still isnt recognizing the touch

Comment: Thanks a ton @Hoan Nguyen... it worked...after putting scroll view as parent of list view it worked...:)

Comment: Good, I wrote my app many months ago and yesterday when I looked at it I did not notice ScrollView. When I did notice it I did not remember the reason for putting it in, but I guess it is there just to get my linear layout to be able to listen for click.

Comment: ohh....This is weird...but whatever it is...thanks a lot...I don't know if I would have got to this solution at all....